# NServiceBus Serialization Issue

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, nservicebus

I am getting this while trying to use NServiceBus DataBus from a console hosted endpoint

```
Type 'NServiceBus.DataBusProperty`1[System.Byte[]]' implements ISerializable but cannot be serialized using the ISerializable interface because the current application is not fully trusted and ISerializable can expose secure data.
To fix this error either change the environment to be fully trusted, change the application to not deserialize the type, add JsonObjectAttribute to the type or change the JsonSerializer setting ContractResolver to use a new DefaultContractResolver with IgnoreSerializableInterface set to true.
Path ''.
```

The same code works fine from a web app .
setting the click-once security setting to fully trusted will cause debugging issues

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I had this in the app config

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
```

which was messing our security policy and this is why Newtonsoft.json didn't treat the console host app as full trusted and didn't feel it was safe to serialize the `DataBus<byte[]>` property